# Reference request: Set of n-Multisets of elements in $\mathbb{N}$ is countable set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, multisets

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed. I need a reference for the statement, that the collection of [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of length $n$ with elements in $\mathbb{N}$ 
\begin{equation}
M_{\mathbb{N}} = \{ \{a_1, ..., a_n\} \mathrm{~is~multiset}| a_i \in \mathbb{N} \}
\end{equation}
is a set and is countable.

Comment: There is a surjection from the finite sequences onto multisets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bijection $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{N}^k$. Now each $\mathbb{N}^k$ is countable and countable unions of countable sets are again countable.